# Google Maps JS API v.3.31 Multiple Markers Render Performance Issue

Tags: javascript, dom, google-maps-api-3

There is a piece of functionality in the project where the google map is used. 
We render maximum 700 markers with the custom icon (red dot in png format). Before the update to v3.31, the render was smooth and quick.

However, after switching to v3.31 the browser freezes once the number of markers is greater than 256 and in the browser (Chrome) console there is a warning:

> [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 5779ms     marker.js:27

Before posting the question here:

1) I checked our implementation, and there were no changes to the creation of markers on our side.

2) Checked release notes for v3.31 (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases)

> 3.31
>   13 February 2018
>   Changes:
>
> - **Make the first 256 Markers DOM Markers by default, then make subsequent     markers Tile Markers. Current default is all Tile Markers.**
> - At high zoom levels (zoomed in) when dragging Pegman, prefer the NEAREST,     rather than the Google-selected BEST panorama.
> - gestureHandling: none now works the same as draggable: false when changed inside a mousedown handler (it now takes effect on mousedown).

3) Checked the DOM when rendering 255 markers and saw only divs, but when rendered > 255 canvases got generated. During the generation of canvases, the browser doesn't respond.

The question is, does anybody stumbled across a similar issue?